# How can I make the cursor the right size on a 4k monitor?

Tags: sfml

Since I have a 4k screen,

```
cursor.loadFromSystem(sf::Cursor::Hand));
```

gives me a cursor that is way too small.

Is there a simple way to make the cursor automatically be the right size? (I want my program to work for people with any screen size).

Comment: Are you sure this is not an issue with dpi on your operating system (i assume you are using windows)?

Comment: I don't know. I just know that when I am in windows my mouse cursor is of normal (visible) size, and when I go into the sfml app the mouse becomes tiny. I would like it to be visible in the sfml app as well, and I was wondering if there exists a simple way to achieve this

Comment: I have personally never used sfml but have you tried calling "SetThreadDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2);"?